# Youtube Data API v3 on file system

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm developing app for Samsung Tizen TV with Youtube Data API v3 (in JavaScript). In older Samsung Smart TVs this app is working correctly, but in new Tizen TV there is problem with authentication. I think it is because older TVs had their own server (localhost), but the new Tizen TV doesn't. (Do you think it is possible?) It works perfectly on localhost or other server, but not without it.

Is there any way I can use Youtube Data API directly from file system (hard disc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already have a solution.

It is possible to run it from file system in Chrome by starting Chrome with argument "--disable-web-security".
In Samsung TV I needed to edit my config.xml file and add `<access origin="*" subdomains="true"/>`. So this wasn't the issue with localhost and servers at all.

It works now in new Tizen TV and from file system on my computer.